# How do you apply a linear model to each row in a dataframe then solve for the model for a specific variable in R?

Tags: r

newbie question.

I have a dataset with many columns, the columns are values at specific x values (A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4).  I want each row to generate a curve based on the column values as y with the x values at those fixed values.  Then I want to solve for y with a particular x.  Then later x for a particular y.  Those values should then be appended to the dataframe as new columns

In short one row: x=(1,2,3,4) y=(2,4,6,8) should give me a line with a slope of 2, an intercept at 0, and a value of 10 for x=5.  Here is what I've tried so far...

```
df <- data.frame(
  Category = c('Number1', 'Number2', 'Number3', 'Number4', 'Number5', 'Number6'),
  A = c(0.8,1,2,0.5,0.6,0.8),
  B = c(1,2,4,1,1.2,1),
  C = c(2.1,3,6,1.5,1.5,2.1),
  D = c(2.4,4,8,2,2.3,2.4)
)

x <- c(1,2,3,4)

df$slope  <-  
  apply(df[, 2:5],
        1,
        function(y){return(coef(lm(y~x))[2])}
  )
df$intercept  <-  
  apply(df[, 2:5],
        1,
        function(y){return(coef(lm(y~x))[1])}
  )
df$xis5  <-  
  apply(df[, 2:5],
        1,
        function(y) {return(predict(lm(y ~ x),x=5, se.fit = TRUE))[0]}
  )
```

But that last column didn't work and gives me

```
> print(df)
  Category   A   B   C   D slope intercept
1  Number1 0.8 1.0 2.1 2.4  0.59      0.10
2  Number2 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0  1.00      0.00
3  Number3 2.0 4.0 6.0 8.0  2.00      0.00
4  Number4 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0  0.50      0.00
5  Number5 0.6 1.2 1.5 2.3  0.54      0.05
6  Number6 0.8 1.0 2.1 2.4  0.59      0.10
                                                                                                                    xis5
1           0.6900000, 1.2800000, 1.8700000, 2.4600000, 0.2268259, 0.1484924, 0.1484924, 0.2268259, 2.0000000, 0.2711088
2                                                                                           1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0
3                                                                                           2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0
4                                                                       0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0
5 0.59000000, 1.13000000, 1.67000000, 2.21000000, 0.12124356, 0.07937254, 0.07937254, 0.12124356, 2.00000000, 0.14491377
6           0.6900000, 1.2800000, 1.8700000, 2.4600000, 0.2268259, 0.1484924, 0.1484924, 0.2268259, 2.0000000, 0.2711088
>
```

Whereas what I want to see for row 2 would be

Category   A   B   C   D slope intercept xis5
Number2 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0  1.00  0.00      10.00

I imagine reversing it would just be y is a value much like x=5 for the reverse prediction but until I figure it out forwards, there's no reason to do it backwards.

While I am aware that it would be fairly simple to algebraically calculate this out (y=slope*5+intercept) I am looking for a solution involving R functions since I want to apply these to higher order polynomial models as well (y ~ poly(x,n))

Please advise, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the method, let me know if I'm mistaken.

The last column should be

```
df$xis5  <-   
apply(df[, 2:5],
        1,function(y) {return(predict(lm(y ~ x),data.frame(x=c(5))))[1]}
  )
print(df)
```

That produces

```
  Category   A   B   C   D slope intercept  xis5
1  Number1 0.8 1.0 2.1 2.4  0.59      0.10  3.05
2  Number2 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0  1.00      0.00  5.00
3  Number3 2.0 4.0 6.0 8.0  2.00      0.00 10.00
4  Number4 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0  0.50      0.00  2.50
5  Number5 0.6 1.2 1.5 2.3  0.54      0.05  2.75
6  Number6 0.8 1.0 2.1 2.4  0.59      0.10  3.05
```

Will now try this on some polynomial models to see if that works as well